# Python Variable Argument to functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, variadic

I am learning Python and came across variadic arguments. I don't understand the output that the following code produces:

```
_list = [11,2,3]
def print_list(*args):
    for value in args:
        a = value * 10
        print(a)
print_list(_list)
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
[11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3, 11, 2, 3]
```

From what I understand, `value` holds one single element from the `_list` array, multiplying it by 10 would produce the list `[110, 20, 30`]. Why does the output differ?

Comment: try doing `print(args)` and I think you'll see why. `args` in your case is `([11,2,3],)` -- a length 1 tuple of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the parameter to your function is `*args` (with a `*`), your function actually receives a tuple of the passed in arguments, so `args` becomes `([11,2,3],)` (a tuple containing the list you passed in).

Your function iterates through the value in that tuple, giving `value=[11,2,3]`. When you multiply a list by 10, you get a list 10 times longer.

Comment: Got it, Thank you... Coming from the C++ background, I mistook *args with pointer-like functionality. Will learn tuples in python now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what are you looking for is expanding the list `print_list(*_list)` which pass each element of the input list as a function parameter and so the output is 
`110 20 30`.

If you would have the list as `numpy.array(_list) * 10` then the multiplications will also work.